# boost::spirit::lex, how does one generate a end of file token?

Tags: token, boost-spirit, eof, boost-spirit-lex

The question is rather simple, I've written a lexer, using boost::spirit, however I can't seem to find a way, to generate an `EOF` token. - So how would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is an EOF token?

> Historically, some platforms have associated special 'EOF' (ascii 26, e.g.) characters with *text files*. Like the [use of 0x15 as newline character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), such uses are now largely defunct. The end of a file is better defined as the absense of further input, in other words: it is a stream state, not a character.

The token iterators Spirit Lex signal 'EOF' by returning the end iterator.

Both the tokenizer API (`lex::tokenize(...)`) as well as Spirit Qi understand this behaviour (by exiting the tokenizing loop (lex) and/or by making the `qi::eoi` parser *succeed match*).

E.g. if you need to assert that parsing reached the end of the input, you'd just say

```
 myrule = subrule1 >> subrule2 > qi::eoi;
```

Or if you want to assert the presence of something (say, a closing `;`) *unless* at end of input:

```
 myrule = subrule1 >> subrule2 >> (qi::eoi | ';');
```

Did I miss something about the question that isn't addressed like this?

Comment: Well it seems like all I ever needed was the `qi::eoi`! However, if I use this in my grammar, then can I assume that all input has been consumed, if the `tokenize_and_parse` function returns true? - That is, can I assume that `(begin == end)`, where begin and end are my input iterators.

Comment: @Skeen If you look at [the header file](http://www.boost.org/boost/spirit/home/qi/auxiliary/eoi.hpp) you can see that all `eoi` does is use the skipper and then simply return whether `first` and `last` are equal (`qi::skip_over(first, last, skipper);return first == last;`). So yes I think you can assume that, if they are not equal the parsing would fail.

Comment: $cv_and_he: Oh wow, I really should have checked the header file, before asking stupid questions.. Anyway thanks :)

Comment: @sehe: Shouldn't there be a `>>` instead of a `>`, in your first code example?

Comment: @Skeen I chose `>` which is the ['expectation operator'](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/expect.html) (as opposed to [`>>` the 'sequence operator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/sequence.html)) because I imagined a requirement _`if you need to assert that parsing reached the end`_. Expectation points fail with an `expectation_failure` if they don't match (instead of 'soft-failing' which allows the calling parser to back-track or attempt alternatives)